# Character start distorting when I moved the body rig

Tags: mesh, rigging, distort

blender community.

Sorry, if this question was asked so many times but I am working on character rigging from months but when I rotate or move any bone of the Rig then the body starts distorting.

I have tried so many solutions but nothing works. Please help.

[Rigged character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2COOM.jpg)[image]

Comment: make sure that the weight paint is correct in Weight Paint mode

Comment: @moonboots you can check this https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tmB-YfBAoJ0acabIHE7ecDu22b_Y6_Tt?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I would personally merge all the character's part to make one object, it would make things easier in my opinion. But first select the armature, display the layer with the deforming bones:

[image]

Then shift select the mesh and check the bones, you can see that some have influence when they should not:

[image]

Select these parts in *Edit* mode, in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Remove From All Groups*, then reassign to the right group (the one that has the name of the bone that is supposed to control) with the *Assign* button. Or do the corrections with a brush (in *Mix* or *Subtract* mode) in *Weight Paint* mode.

[image]

For the smoothness yo could add a *Subdivision Surface* under your *Armature* modifier, but you should add edge loops where the bending is happening (by the way, no need for so many horizontal edges in my opinion, especially if you add a *Subdivision Surface*):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Moonboots for the answer. Problem is not the ear actual arms & legs are distorted & there are not smooth.

Comment: I've edited my answer, the problem is the same, you need to give some corrections, check each bone and correct their influence in Weight Paint mode.